# C#|Start Remote Desktop as a Process + Put text in the textbox

Tags: c#

well, the title of this qustions is abit stupid, but i will expline it very very simple.

in my code, i am strating a remote deskop.exe

like this:

```
Process rtc;
    rtc = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe");
```

now, the thing is. when the remote deskop comes up(its work) i will like to know how can i put a name in the textbox on the connction.

so when the remote will be up, the conntion name will be there, or a ip.

is it even posibale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `/v` argument:

```
Process.Start("mstsc.exe", string.Format("/v:{0}:{1}", server, port));
```

Answer (score 5):

mstsc has a lot of command line parameters you can pass to it:

```
MSTSC [<connection file>] [/v:<server[:port]>] [/admin] [/f[ullscreen]] [/w:<width> /h:<height>] [/public] | [/span] [/multimon] [/migrate] [/edit "connection file"]

"connection file" -- Specifies the name of an .RDP file for the connection.

/v:<server[:port]> -- Specifies the remote computer to which you want to connect.

/admin -- Connects you to the session for administering a server.

/f -- Starts Remote Desktop in full-screen mode.

/w:<width> -- Specifies the width of the Remote Desktop window.

/h:<height> -- Specifies the height of the Remote Desktop window.

/public -- Runs Remote Desktop in public mode.

/span -- Matches the remote desktop width and height with the local virtual desktop, spanning across multiple monitors, if necessary. To span across monitors, the monitors must be arranged to form a rectangle.

/multimon -- Configures the remote desktop session monitor layout to be identical to the current client-side configuration.

/edit -- Opens the specified .RDP connection file for editing.

/migrate -- Migrates legacy connection files that were created with Client Connection Manager to new .RDP connection files.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can launch `mstsc.exe` with the parameter **-v:**`<remoteip|remotemachine>` to achieve the same ( the user will be prompt for the login credentials )